# Getting max value using relation on two table

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, join, greatest-n-per-group

Using postgresql I have to build two tables named country and neighbour. Here is the query that I wrote.

```
CREATE TABLE country (
    cid         INTEGER     PRIMARY KEY,
    cname       VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    height      INTEGER     NOT NULL,
    population  INTEGER     NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE neighbour (
    country     INTEGER     REFERENCES country(cid) ON DELETE RESTRICT,
    neighbor    INTEGER     REFERENCES country(cid) ON DELETE RESTRICT, 
    length      INTEGER     NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(country, neighbor)
);
```

Now I want the question I am stuck on is for each country I have to find a neighbor country with highest elevation point. I have to report its id and name

I have to get country's id and name and it's neighbouring country's id and name with highest elevation point.

```
SELECT country.cid,country.cname,foo.cid,foo.cname
from country,(SELECT cid,cname
from country
    join neighbour
        on country.cid = neighbour.neighbor) as foo
group by country.cid, country.cname, foo.cid, foo.cname;
```

This is what I have done but I don't where to add max() clause to find the highest elevation point.

Answer (score 1):

You can use joins and distinct on:

```
select distinct on (c1.cid, c1.cname)
    c1.cid, 
    c1.cname, 
    c2.cid neighbour_cid, 
    c2.cname, neighbour_name
from country c1
inner join neighbour n on n.cid = c1.cid
inner join country c2 on c2.cid = n.neighbour
order by c1.cid, c1.cname, c2.height desc
```

For each country, the query follows the relationship through bridge table `neighbour` table and, recovers all neighbours by joining `country` a second time. Then, `distinct on` keeps the neigbour with the greatest `height` only.